# jQuery .text() shows double text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have a strange situation happening. I have a `<h3>` with text in it. When I extract this text with .text() and then put this into a `<textarea>` the text appears twice.

[Here is jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Putpe/4/)

**HTML**

```
<h3 class="profileRightAboutMeText">Heya, this is all the text.</h3>     
<textarea class="profileRightAboutMeTextarea"></textarea>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('click','h6.editMyProfileSection', function() {
  var originalText = $('h3.profileRightAboutMeText').text();

  $('h3.profileRightAboutMeText').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $('textarea.profileRightAboutMeTextarea').text(originalText).fadeIn('fast');
  });
  alert(originalText);
});
```

Both the alert and `<textarea>` show the text double as follows:

Heya, this is all the text.Heya, this is all the text.

Comment: It seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ehzx4/ Are you sure you don't have multiple `h3` elements on the page with a class of `profileRightAboutMeText`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would say that you have 2 elements that match $('h3.profileRightAboutMeText') on the page.

You can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/KwcGB/ that the text appears twice because I added an extra h3.profileRightAboutMeText to the html but if the extra line is removed then it only appears once.

Try putting $('h3.profileRightAboutMeText') into the console in firebug and seeing how many elements it matches...

Answer (score 13):

JQuery has different behavior for `text()` method in case of duplicates which are addressed by compound path.

For example, let

```
<div id=b class="a">2</div>
<div id=b class="a">3</div>
```

Then

```
var val1 = $("#b").text()
var val2 = $("#b.a").text()

// val1 = 2
// val2 = 23
```

To avoid this problem use .first() for sure

```
var val3 = $("#b.a").first().text()

// val3 = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

For form elements you should use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `text()`:

```
$("textarea.profileRightAboutMeTextarea").val(originalText)
```

Additionally, check if you have duplicates of elements with class `profileRightAboutMeText`.

Comment: @barlasapaydin: The fiddle doesn't copy the original text into the textbox, which seems to be a requirement.

Comment: @barlasapaydin Your example can't work because you use `val()` method for `<h3>` element. Here is the correct fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Putpe/8/.

Comment: @VisioN  **Than show us a working one.** Note: Here is not working version which op asked on his question: http://jsfiddle.net/Putpe/4/

Comment: @VisioN: Though your answer is giving correct advise it does not seem to be the reason the text is duplicated in the text area. Event the code posted b y OP does not duplicate the text in the fiddle and works as expected. There seems to be more `h3` elements in the HTML.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl The reason should be in duplicates. I mentioned it in the answer.

Comment: @VisioN: Ah, yes, for some reason that part of the answer was not on my page until I refreshed.